# Передача данных из razor в контроллер asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Передача данных из контроллера в представление.

Не получается передать данные с представление в параметр через Razor

```
@Html.EditorFor(Count => line.Quantity,
 new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", min = "1",
 max = "100", @class = "form-control",
 @name = "Count", @id = "Count" } })
```

Через обычный html проблем не возникает.

```
<input type="text" name="Count" id="Count"/>
```

Как через razor передать значение? @name = "Count", @id = "Count" указал, не пойму в чем дело

Comment: какой html получается?

Comment: Да все, я кажется понял. Имя параметра как в лямбде должно быть то есть Quantity, т.к хелпер берет id, name как раз от него

Comment: Хотя не все так просто, потому что выражение записывается не к примеру так Count => Count.Quantity, а там добавляется последовательность Count => line.Quantity.

Comment: В общем, как вариант записать так.

Comment: @Html.Editor("Quantity", new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", min = "1", max = "100", @class = "form-control" } }

Comment: Но есть один минус, нельзя будет получать в форму значение из модели, поле будет всегда пустое изначально при загрузке страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы решить Вашу проблему, напишите:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(Count => line.Quantity,
 new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", min = "1",
 max = "100", @class = "form-control",
 Name = "Count", id = "Count" } })
```

Т.е. требуется вместо `@name`, написать `Name` и Ваша проблема будет решена.
Отмечу, что `@` отмечаются только те атрибуты, которые представляют собой ключевые слова в языке C# (такие как `class`, `readonly` и т.п.), в остальных случаях он является необязательным.

Решение находилось в первой ссылке гугла. 
[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057865/asp-net-mvc-3-override-name-attribute-with-textboxfor)

Comment: Странно но дело не в собаке, потестил разными способами. Срабатывает только тогда, когда Name с заглавной буквы. И разницы нету с @ или без. id вообще ни на что не повлияло в тестах, как с ним так и без него - работает

Comment: То есть для таких вот хелперов, надо писать Name с заглавной буквы и все будет ок

Comment: @SOFL По этому я указал, что `@` является необязательной, т.е. можно вводить, можно нет. Просто зачем вводить лишние символы.